# how to change the log4j log file dynamically?

Tags: java, logging

I want to have a log4j configuration such that the log file name should have like ${System-name}log.log. that is if the application is launched on any system then without changing the configuration file or code. it should generate the log file name as mentioned.
thanks.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201188/using-system-environment-variables-in-log4j-xml-configuration

Answer (score 3):

I do it this way:
1) init logger by:

```
System.setProperty("my.logsDir", vcsLogsDir);
DOMConfigurator.configure("c:/log4j.xml");
```

2) in log4j.xml i use variable:

```
<param name="File" value="${my.logsDir}Default.log"/>d
```

Comment: Can you please tell me, how it can set log4j.xml file's related relative path rather than absolute path ex:  DOMConfigurator.configure("../log4j.xml") . thanks.

Comment: You can set relative path exactly as you has written ("../log4j.xml"). It will find your log4j.xml relatively to your working directory.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I got it with ContextClassLoader as:  DOMConfigurator.configure(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader.getResource(".").getPath() + "log4j.xml")

Comment: I am afraid, that it will not work if your log4j.xml is zipped inside jar/war. You should load your log4j.xml regullary from classpath. Or copy it from classpath into some temp directory.

Comment: Yes your are correct, it will not work with a executable jar. Many thanks for the worth full feedback. As you mention I have tried with relative path for log4j.xml but it was not working. When it call on under "com.org.abc.util" package and "log4j.xml" is on inside the jar file, whether I can define relative path as "..\\...\\..\\..\\log4j.xml" or whether I should copy the log4j.xml some directory out side the jar file and have to give that path as "Dlog4j.configuration=resources/log4j.xml". Can you please help me to set log4j.xml file path. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have accomplished the issue as, URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("log4j.xml"); DOMConfigurator.configure(url). Many thanks. Have a nice time!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java system properties with the `${property}` syntax. There are number of system properties that are defined by default including

```
"os.arch"     Operating system architecture
"os.name"     Operating system name
"os.version"  Operating system version
```

For a full list of default properties see API of [System](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29) or list them with `System.getProperties().list(System.out)`.

If the default properties won't do then you'll have top add your own properties using `System.setProperty(property, value)`.