# Log4J change File path dynamically

Tags: java, dynamic, properties, log4j

I want to change the path and file name of my log4j logfile dynamically.

I have read a lot of pages and nearly every tell me that I should use system properties like here:
[how to change the log4j log file dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006476/how-to-change-the-log4j-log-file-dynamically)

So my log4j.properties file looks like this:

```
log4j.logger.JDBC_LOGGER=INFO,jdbcTests
log4j.additivity.JDBC_LOGGER = false

log4j.appender.jdbcTests=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.jdbcTests.File=${my.log}
log4j.appender.jdbcTests.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.jdbcTests.append = false
log4j.appender.jdbcTests.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy mm dd HH:mm:ss} %5p %C:Line %L - %m%n
```

In my main method I am going to set my new system property:

```
System.setProperty("{my.log", "C:/logfile.log");
```

But I just get an error:

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,false) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)....
```

And when I try to read my set system property with:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("my.log"));
```

it return null.
What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you meant "my.log" not "{my.log"

```
System.setProperty("my.log", "C:/logfile.log");
```

I wouldn't imagine you can change this once the logging has started so you need to set this as early in your program as possible.

BTW: You can sub-class FileAppender to make it behave any way you like.

Comment: Ok sorry for my mistake. I changed it to `System.setProperty("my.log", "C:/logfile.log");`
I set this in the first line of my main method but I still get the same error

Comment: Just to add: `System.out.println(System.getProperty("my.log"));` works fine now. But I still cant change the log path dynamically

Comment: `log4j:ERROR setFile(null,false) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\logfile.log (Zugriff verweigert)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)`
Zugriff verweigert = access denied

Comment: Can you change it to a directory you can access? If you have a `static Log` in the class for your main, this will be called first. You may need to add a static block at the very start of the class which contains your  `main()`

Comment: Thank you I also just got it. I used:
`private static Logger logger = null;`

and in the Main i wrote:

`System.setProperty("my.log", "C:/Workspace/logfile.log");
logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());`

Now everything works very well:)

Comment: You can do `static { System.setProperty("my.log", "C:/Workspace/logfile.log"); } private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());` at the very start.

Answer (score 1):

You have a misspelling: "{my.log" instead of "my.log"

Answer (score 0):

Just set property before instantiating logger, once you initilize the logger setting the property will not worth. just like below:

```
System.setProperty("my.log", "C:\\src\\com\\web\\automation\\logs\\Application.log");
PP_LOGS = Logger.getLogger("devpinoyLogger");
```