# Log4j: add parameter to log file name

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, log4j

I have web application and I log some info on user requests. I need to include client ip address in a log file name, so I'd get separate log file for each ip. Can I define some file naming pattern with parameters (ip in my case)? I have string ip variable.

File name example: `mylog-127.0.0.1.log`

Thanks

Comment: Could I just suggest if you are going this way, from an ordering point of view, `mylog-127.000.000.001.log` instead as a naming convention?

Comment: @David M doesn't matter, it could be session ID or anything else, but thanks anyway

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006476/how-to-change-the-log4j-log-file-dynamically

Comment: If you use client IP in naming the log files, the amounts of those log files will be huge, are you sure you want it like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, I need to create appenders dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If you can switch to logback, I suggest you use [SiftingAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) instead.