# Log4j logging to separate files

Tags: java, networking, log4j

I have an application that listens on a specific port to do its task.
This application can run on multiple instances by specifying different
ports in the argument.

MyApp-1211.bat contains

```
java MyApp 1211
```

MyApp-1311.bat contains

```
java MyApp 1311
```

MyApp-1411.bat contains

```
java MyApp 1411
```

This application logs to a file. The problem is all three instances log
into a single file, `myApp.log`. Is there a way to tell log4j to use
different log files? like:

```
myApp-port1211.log  
myApp-port1311.log  
myApp-port1411.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can. One way would be to create multiple configuration files (log4j.xml / log4j.properties) - one per port respectively process. Upon loading the configuration file you could select the correct one based on the current port number:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j-" + port + ".properties");
```

Create the config files accordingly: *log4j-1211.properties*, *log4j-1311.properties*, ...

The alternative would be to configure the file logging at runtime via Java code:

```
String logFilename = "./myApp-port" + port + ".log";
Layout layout = new PatternLayout("%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t] %c{1}: %m%n");
FileAppender fileAppender = new FileAppender(layout, logFilename, false);
fileAppender.setThreshold(Level.DEBUG);
Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(fileAppender);
```

Comment: is the same possible on a configuration file cause am currently using a log4j properties file

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to system properties in log4j.xml as following:

```
<appender name="ROLL" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
                <!-- The active file to log to -->
                <param name="file" value="mylog${MY_PARAM}.log" />
</appender>
```

Now you just have to insert your parameter into system properties either programmatically `System.setProperty("MY_PARAM", args[0])` into your `main()` method or when you are running java:

`java -DMY_PARAM=1234 MyApp 1234`

Obiously you can avoid dupplication if you are running you application from bat or shell script like:

`java -DMY_PARAM=%1 MyApp %1`

Please see the following references for details:

http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat

[Using system environment variables in log4j xml configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201188/using-system-environment-variables-in-log4j-xml-configuration)

Comment: how does this translate to a properties file instead of an xml file?

Answer (score 0):

If you go for loading the property configuration file yourself, as suggested by other answers, don't forget to disable the log4j default initialization by adding the env. variable definition to your program's command line:

```
-Dlog4j.defaultInitOverride=true
```

Comment: @user960740 Log4j has a built-in default initialization within a static code block that's likely executed before you have a chance to do something about it. This environment variable prevents this execution. You may want to do this to make sure you're starting with exactly the configuration you want.