# log4j - Access environment variables

Tags: java, log4j

I put the following environment variable in the CATALINA.BAT

```
set "APACHE_WEB_DIRECTORY=C:/wamp/www/DuInvestColombo"
```

i tried to access the variable as follow

```
apacheWebDirectory=${APACHE_WEB_DIRECTORY}
```

but it didn't work, logs did not writtent to the directory

```
log4j.appender.applicationLogsFileAppender.File=${apacheWebDirectory}/ApplicationLogs.log
```

what is the correct way to get this environment variable to log4j

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using system environment variables in log4j xml configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201188/using-system-environment-variables-in-log4j-xml-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

The PropertyConfigurator in log4j used the OptionConverter to replace ${name} variables in the property file. But the value for the conversion is taken from the system-properties, not from the environment.

Where did you try to access the variable as "apacheWebDir="{APACHE_WEB_DIR}"? The .bat file only knows variable substitution by %

As you are using a .bat file, your call to start the java program has to include:

```
-DapacheWebDirectory=%APACHE_WEB_DIRECTORY
```