# Is it possible to use unix env vars in log4j.properties?

Tags: java, unix, log4j

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using system environment variables in log4j xml configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201188/using-system-environment-variables-in-log4j-xml-configuration)

Need to configure logging appender (e.g. log4j.appender.DBSGENAPPENDER.File property) using env vars?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201188/using-system-environment-variables-in-log4j-xml-configuration

Comment: Solved
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201188/using-system-environment-variables-in-log4j-xml-configuration