# Dynamic fileName File Appender log4j2

Tags: java, yaml, log4j2

I'd like to set dynamically the fileName where the FileAppender will write.
I'll provide an example of my configuration.

log4j2.yml

```
...

  Appenders:

    Console:

      name: Console_Appender

      target: SYSTEM_OUT

      PatternLayout:

        pattern: "[%-5level] %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"

    File:

      name: File_Appender

      fileName: ${log-path}/fileLog.log


      PatternLayout:

        pattern: "[%-5level] %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"
...
```

I'd like *fileLog${javaVariable}.log* where *javaVariable* is dynamic.
Is this possible?

Thank you :)

EDIT: To be clear
I need that if the method that I intercept with @Around annotation is called by the user0 I have to write the (single) log in "user0.log"; if is called by user1 -> "user1.log".
I can create users at any time so I need a dynamic filename.

Comment: I think it might help were you to be more specific about 'dynamic'. You mean as in "decided as a parameter to the app to be run" or "set inside the code at runtime"…

Comment: [Using system environment variables in log4j xml configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201188/using-system-environment-variables-in-log4j-xml-configuration)

Comment: @g00se Dynamic = set inside the code at runtime

Comment: @LeiYang I need to use yml :(
However, I have already used _${sys:logFile}_ and in java _System.setProperty("logFile", "theFileName")_ but doesn't work. Are you sure that works with yml?

Comment: i think yaml is same. how about `${logFile}` in yaml, and `java -DlogFile=xyz`?

Comment: @LeiYang I need to set the variable runtime not boottime :(

Comment: i think you need code, not config. [Configuring Log4j Loggers Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965946/configuring-log4j-loggers-programmatically)

Comment: In that case you can look at the api and [examples](https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j/how-to-programmatically-configure-appenders-in-log4j/)

Comment: @g00se Ok.
Logger.getRootLogger() is undefined.

Log4j2 is not log4j

Comment: I was going to say, but forgot sorry, that the code there is old. It's now `LogManager` that gets `Logger`s

Comment: @g00se there are a lot of setter that doesn't exists...
However, if I can create a file appender and etc, how can I say "write this with this logger"? The method FileAppender.append needs LogEvent and I don't know how to create it...
I have edited the answer so now it's more specific. Can you read again, please?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is MDC.
I've used [this guide](https://roytuts.com/how-to-create-separate-log-file-for-each-module-using-routingappender-and-mdc-mapped-diagnostic-context-in-log4j2-slf4j/) where you can use Routing to select the file according to a variable in the Thread context.